# Boolean Algebra: Convert F(a,b,c,d) = a'bd + ac'd

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm attempting to simply convert the following boolean expression to using only NOR logic:
f(a,b,c,d) = a'bd + ac'd

The correct answer is
NOR( NOR(a',c'), NOR(a,b), d')

I've converted the solution to the following to compare to my work:
NOR( ac, a'b', d')

The following are two attempts which lead to the same scenario of being stuck:
[image: Image of My Work]

If I can get rid of the cb' term then I believe I'll have the right answer, but I'm unable to figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.
*This is a practice exam not hw

Comment: You can just define AND, OR, and NOT in terms of (binary...) NOR. Once you've done that you can simply substitute these definition for the use of the operators in your source formula. This won't produce the simplest output, but it is a completely mechanical process.

Comment: You should probably also clarify what you mean by "NOR logic". What I would take that to mean is a logic using only binary NOR gates, but it appears that you mean something like having an arbitrary arity "NOR" gate which is defined as the negation of the disjunction of all inputs (which means NOT is just the unary case, and presumably 1 is the nullary case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem) states that:

$xy+x'z+yz=xy+x'z$

So, applied to your expression:

$ac+a'b'+b'c=ac+a'b'$

So yes, you can indeed get rid of the $b'c$ term.

If you don't like to use the consensus Theorem directly:

$ac+a'b'+b'c=ac+a'b'+b'c1=ac+a'b'+b'c(a+a')=$

$ac+a'b'+ab'c+a'b'c=ac(1+b')+a'b'(1+c)=ac1+a'b'1=ac+a'b'$